# File upload not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to upload a file from my application and it is not working as expected. I am not getting any file into the action method.

I have my viewmodel as below

```
public class CallQueryViewModel
{
        [Display(Name = "Attachment")]        
        public HttpPostedFileBase UploadFile { get; set; }
}
```

And my Razor form is as below

```
@{
    var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "onCallAddBegin",
        OnSuccess = "OnCallCreateSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnCallCreateFailure"
    };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCall", "CallHandling", ajaxOptions, new { @id = "CallAddForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UploadFile, new { @class = "col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UploadFile, new { @class = "col-md-10", type="file" })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
}
```

And my controller action method is as below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddCall(CallQueryViewModel model)
    {
        if ((model.UploadFile != null) && (model.UploadFile.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            // Upload file.
        }
    }
```

With the above code, when i am trying to upload the file, I am not receiving any file into the controller action method. The UploadFile is always coming as null.

Could someone suggest what I am missing ?

Comment: You cannot upload a file via AJAX, it has been discussed many times on SO. Use regular HTML form, [HTML 5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), jQuery plugins or just search for the similar questions.

Comment: you can serialize your form and post it to server via ajax

Comment: @Zabavsky Thanks. I do not know you can upload files with Ajax. I have used the jquery forms plugin and it works perfectly.